# LINQ throwing invalid cast exception on a bigint

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ query that looks something like this:

```
var clintLst = (from clntDt in ent.ClientDatas
                where clntDt.CompanyName.Substring(0,searchWord.Length).Equals(searchWord, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                orderby clntDt.CompanyName
                select new { ClientDataID = clntDt.ClientDataID,
                    CompanyName = clntDt.CompanyName, 
                    ContactName = (clntDt.ContactFirstName + " " + clntDt.ContactLastName),
                    CompanyLocation = clntDt.Location.LocationCity.CityName + ", " + clntDt.Location.LocationState.StateCode
                } ).Distinct().Take(10);
```

However, it is throwing the following exception:

> The specified cast from a materialized
>   'System.Int32' type to the
>   'System.Int64' type is not valid. [..]
>   Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   specified cast from a materialized
>   'System.Int32' type to the
>   'System.Int64' type is not valid.
>
> Source File:
>   C:\TempPersonalCode\TransportTracking\TransportTracking\TransportTracking\Controllers\AJAXController.cs
>   Line: 35

(Line 35 is the select clause)

I'm confused because if change:

```
select new { ClientDataID = clntDt.ClientDataID,
    CompanyName = clntDt.CompanyName,
```

to

```
select new { ClientDataID = (Int32)clntDt.ClientDataID,
    CompanyName = clntDt.CompanyName,
```

then it works fine. Isn't an anonymous object supposed to use reflection to determine it's type? if so, why is it deciding that it's an "Int32" instead of a long? Within the EDMX I have it as an Int64.

Comment: An anonymous object doesn't use reflection at all. It infers the type at compile time, based on the return type of `ClientDataID`.

Comment: @vcsjones: All the more then reason why this is confusing :P
But thanks for correcting me on that.

Answer (score 19):

The phrase "materialized value" refers to the value that was retrieved from the data store.

What's probably happening is that the database has that column configured as an `int`, but in your EDMX file it's a `long` (or `Int64`).

The `(Int32)` cast you're putting on the front is (probably) being translated to the data store (in SQL Server, this means something like `CAST([columnName] AS int)`, and consequently, the Entity Framework is now *expecting* to get an `int` instead of a `long`.

Without the cast, it's expecting a `long` but getting an `int`.

The solution is to either change the EDMX file or change the column, so that the data type in the EDMX file matches the data type in the database.

(jhott)

Comment: But what is the Solution Ryan

Comment: I've added a sentence to my answer, explaining how to fix the problem.

Comment: This helped me. I had a Stored Procedure which was returning an average in seconds. So when I dropped the Stored Procedure onto the DBML, it got auto-generated as a `long?`, however, in the Stored Procedure, where I have no data to average, I just did `SELECT 0` to return 0 (zero). Now that meant that the Stored Procedure was sending an `int?` back to the calling code when there was no data to average, and hence it was giving me `InvalidCastException`. Sometimes it was working by sending a `long?` and sometimes was sending an `int?`.

Answer (score 2):

In my stored procedure, I was returning `row number` and `rowcount`, I casted it to `int` and it works properly now.

```
CAST (TotalCount AS INT)TotalCount
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception seems to be thrown from the Entity Framework. You might have the column set as `int` instead of `bigint` in the SSDL file.

Comment: This was one of the first things I checked. I'll have to check it again tomorrow but I'm pretty sure I had it set to bigint.

Comment: Yeup, sure enough- in the properties for this field within the EDMX I have it as an Int64... any other ideas?

Comment: Not really. Your best bet is probably to ask at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/adodotnetentityframework/