# concat results of select with complex types

Tags: entity-framework

I have bellow class :

```
public class KardeksKalaComplexColumnInfoM{

private decimal _Qty;
        public decimal Qty
        {
            get { return _Qty; }
            set
            {
                if (_Qty != value)
                {
                    _Qty = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Qty");
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Total");
                }
            }
        }

private decimal _Fee;
        public decimal Fee
        {
            get { return _Fee; }
            set
            {
                if (_Fee != value)
                {
                    _Fee = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Fee");
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Total");
                }
            }
        }

public decimal Total
        {
            get { return Qty * Fee; } 
        }
}
```

and a context contains buys and sales,i run bellow code and results commented in three last lines:

```
var q_buys = (
                            from
                                r_d in _db.BuyDetails

                            select new KardeksKalaDetailM()
                            {
                                ID = r_d.ID,
                                Date = r_d.Date,
                                in = new KardeksKalaComplexColumnInfoM() {Qty = r_d.Qty, Fee = r_d.Fee },
                            });


var q_sales = (
                            from
                                r_d in _db.SaleDetails
                            select new KardeksKalaDetailM()
                            {
                                ID = r_d.ID,
                                Date = r_d.Date,
                                in = new KardeksKalaComplexColumnInfoM() { Qty=0 , Fee=0 },

                            });
var q1=q_buys.ToList(); // Ok
var q2=q_sales.ToList(); // Ok
var result=q_buys.Concat(q_sales).ToList();  // Error
```

when I change the KardeksKalaComplexColumnInfoM filed types to double the last line's error solved but when them types are decimal it has bellow error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Int64' type is not valid.
```

how can resolve last line problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826919/linq-throwing-invalid-cast-exception-on-a-bigint